# How to get 888888 number of response from an API , by putting number only in API path like www.example.com/111111

Tags: java, spring-boot, logic

I have a third-party API  that gives me the data from the 111111 to 999999 range.
the API like `www.example.con/{path_value}`, If I put the value from 111111 to 999999 as path variable it gives me the data that can I store in my DB. I have already used this to get the response and save it into my DB.
I am using the normal for loop from 111111 to 999999,  my service code snippet is.

```
    public boolean storeData() {
        
        boolean bool = false;
        for (int i = 111111; i < 999999; i++) {  // Here we iterate 888888 times which will take more than 3 days

            String uri = "https://www.example.com/"+i; // here the URL will be formed dynamically like https://thirdparty.api/111111
            ------
            #Here calling of above URI as rest call and store its response into DB.
            bool = true;
        }

        return bool;
    }
```

From a range of i= 111111 to 999999, it will use 888888 iterations, and on average 2 iterations took 1 second. By this, it will take 3 to 4 days to complete.
Could it be any possible solution in java and spring so that I can get this within minuts?

Comment: re *// here the URL will be formed dynamically like https: //thirdparty.api/111111*  Well, no.  You're getting `https: //www.example.com/https: //www.example.com/111111`, then `https: //www.example.com/https: //www.example.com/111111https: //www.example.com/https: //www.example.com/111111111112`, then `https: //www.example.com/https: //www.example.com/111111https: //www.example.com/https: //www.example.com/111111111112https: //www.example.com/https: //www.example.com/111111https: //www.example.com/https: //www.example.com/111111111112111113`, ....  (extra space added to stop treatment as link)

Answer (score 1):

Consider these factors while writing this logic

1- Singleton  Rest Template with TCP keep alive flag.

2- Consider processing records in batches, split records in batches and once you have response for the complete batch, insert it in the DB.

3- Process records in a particular batch in parallel. Keep track of the failed batches for retry later. Use executor framework.

4- Consider having correct connection pool if you are planning to do parallel processing, less number of available connection should not become performance bottleneck. Consider using Hikari connection pool. This will also avoid degrading your DB performance like eating away all the connections and locking table.

5- If this batch has to execute daily, consider using solution like Kafka to have better control of your transaction.

6-  If you want to go with low code no code approach, you can go for some etl tool like Talend I I do this kind of operation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! An answer to question should include code snippet or pseudo code instead of plain steps.

Answer (score 0):

To use all available CPU cores, use a parallel stream:

```
IntStream.range(11111, 99999).parallelStream()
  .forEach(i -> <do something with i>);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Spring Boot's Async annotation to parallelize the REST calls. But understand using multiple threads won't magically improve performance. You need to see if you actually have multiple processors in the servers, and how many. And then tweak the number of threads in the thread pool accordingly. For starters, start with the same number of threads as the number of processors(With hyperthreading, one core can handle two threads at a time).

https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

You will need to refactor your code a little.

1. Make the rest template singleton.
2. Move the rest calls to a different method. Annotate the new method as Async, and call this new method within the for loop passing it the path_value.

Comment: Here the point is not for rest template use, My question actually for how can I do 8 lack iteration effectively and parallel.